# append characters in arraylist in a specific position

Tags: java, append

```
public void reveal(char c) {

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeReset; i++) {
        if(wordCompare.charAt(i) == c)  revealed.set(i);
        if(revealed.cardinality() == 0) {
            eo.add(String.valueOf('*'));
        }
        else {
            if(revealed.get(i) == true) {
                eo.add(String.valueOf(wordCompare.charAt(i)));
            }
            else {
                eo.add(String.valueOf('*'));
            }
        }

}
    System.out.println(eo.toString());
    jTextPane1.setText(eo.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "")); 
}
```

Note:

String wordCompare - contains the word to guess.

char c - is the letter being entered by the user

revealed - is a declared as a BitSet

int sizeReset - is the size of the word to guess

ASSUME THAT ArrayList eo = new ArrayList(); is declared outside the method. (global)

=============================================

This is what I have so far. Let's say I'll be guessing "banana". the entered letter by the user will be shown, and the rest will be marked as "*".

===========================================

PROBLEM: It appends the entire values including the "*" to the end of the stored values in the arrayList and not in the specific position that I want them to be.(also the "*" should not be included when it appends. only the letters that the user entered). *THE LOGIC OF THE HANGMAN GAME.

SAMPLE:

first letter entered: "a"

OUTPUT:

_a_a_a

second letter entered: "n"

OUTPUT:

_ _n_n_

(which is wrong)

The correct OUTPUT should be:

_anana

===============================================

I'm new to String manipulation and I'm having trouble with this part. I've read something about StringBuilder but I haven't figured it out yet. It would be really great if you can help me. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this can be done using `StringBuilder`. You just need to replace the `char`s at the indices in the original `String` that contained the `char` with the `char`, which can be done using [`setCharAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt-int-char-).

The following code also keeps whitespace characters the same, which is the reason for the special treatment of whitespaces in the constructor.

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;

public class StringReveal {

    private final String original;

    private final StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    private String currentString;
    private int missingLetters;

    public StringReveal(String original, char placeholder) {
        if (original.indexOf(placeholder) >= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("placeholder must not be contained in the string");
        }

        if (Character.isWhitespace(placeholder)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("placeholder must not be a whitespace character");
        }

        this.original = original;
        this.stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        this.missingLetters = original.length();

        for (char c : original.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                // keep whitespace characters the same
                missingLetters--;
                stringBuilder.append(c);
            } else {
                // replace everything else with placeholder char
                stringBuilder.append(placeholder);
            }
        }
        this.currentString = stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public void reveal(char c) {
        int index = original.indexOf(c);
        if (index < 0 || currentString.charAt(index) == c) {
            // if letter was already replaced or does not exist in the original
            // there's nothing to do
            return;
        }

        do {
            // replace char
            stringBuilder.setCharAt(index, c);
            missingLetters--;

            // find next char
            index = original.indexOf(c, index + 1);
        } while (index >= 0);

        currentString = stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public String getCurrentString() {
        return currentString;
    }

    public int getMissingLetters() {
        return missingLetters;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringReveal stringReveal = new StringReveal("banana bread", '*');

        char[] guesses = {'a', 'x', 't', 'a', 'b', 'k', 'n', 'g', 'd', ' ',  '*', 'r', 'w', 'e'};

        System.out.println("Try to guess this sting: " + stringReveal.getCurrentString());

        for (char guess : guesses) {
            stringReveal.reveal(guess);
            System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Current String: {0} ; guess: ''{1}''; you still have to guess {2} letters",
                    stringReveal.getCurrentString(),
                    guess,
                    stringReveal.getMissingLetters()));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much, but is there a way where I can preserve the white spaces? that's the only thing that my program is lacking.

Comment: Can pls you spare me a little bit of your time sir by editing the code for the minor revisions regarding the white spaces? so that I can mark this as the correct answer. which it is BTW even without the minor revisions, but it would be great if you can add it. I'm really new to string manipulation and I can't fully understand the code that you provided. I'm still in the process of understanding it. This is for the benefit of the others too who are experiencing the same problem. Once again, Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that you store the ArrayList containing the replaced characters in the reveal method. This means that the ArrayList gets created new every time a character is entered. To fix this problem, you have to store the ArrayList outside of the reveal method like this:

```
package xyz;

public class Name{

     public ArrayList<String> eo = new ArrayList<String>();

     public void reveal(char c){
          // Reveal Code here
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have already tried that. It appends to the end of the stored values in arrayList but not in their proper location where I want them to be. Pls take a look at the input and output sample that I have provided.

Comment: Your getting it wrong. You have to move the ArrayList out of the reveal(char c) method. See code example above.

Comment: I already did. I made it global sir, if that is what you are pointing out. It only appends to the end of the values that are stored in the arrayList.

Comment: Is the result different then you are describing in your question now? Because in your question, you are stating that the output after the second character is completely replaced, not appended.

Comment: Yes, but it's not the result that I want. Pardon me may question be wrong. I will edit it Asap.