# Gradually and randomly visualize string

Tags: ios, swift, iteration

I am currently working on a simple program to gradually and randomly visualize a string in two iteration. Right now I have managed to get the first iteration but I'm not sure how to do the second one. If someone could give any example or advice I would be very grateful. My code looks like this:

```
let s = "Hello playground"
let factor = 0.25
let factor2 = 0.45

var n = s.filter({ $0 != " " }).count  // # of non-space characters
var m = lrint(factor * Double(n))      // # of characters to display

let t = String(s.map { c -> Character in
        if c == " " {
        // Preserve space
        return " "
    } else if Int.random(in: 0..<n) < m {
        // Replace
        m -= 1
        n -= 1
        return c
    } else {
        // Keep
        n -= 1
        return "_"
    }
})

print(t)  // h_l__ _l_______d
```

To clarify, I want to use factor2 in the second iteration to print something that randomly add letters on top of `t` that looks something like this h_l_o pl_g_____d.

Comment: That code [looks familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54202228/1187415)  :)

Comment: Hahah, I hope so :), I thought it worked nicely for this purpose and it is quite clean.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38071061/2907715

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Replacing Characters

Starting from **@MartinR**'s code, you should remember the indices that have been replaced. So, I am going to slightly change the code that replaces characters :

```
let s = "Hello playground"
let factor = 0.25
let factor2 = 0.45

var n = s.filter({ $0 != " " }).count  // # of non-space characters
let nonSpaces = n
var m = lrint(factor * Double(n))      // # of characters to display

var indices = Array(s.indices)

var t = ""

for i in s.indices {
    let c = s[i]
    if c == " " {
        // Preserve space
        t.append(" ")
        indices.removeAll(where: { $0 == i })
    } else if Int.random(in: 0..<n) < m {
        // Keep
        m -= 1
        n -= 1
        t.append(c)
        indices.removeAll(where: { $0 == i })
    } else {
        // Replace
        n -= 1
        t.append("_")
    }
}

print(t)   //For example: _e___ ______ou_d
```

### Revealing Characters

In order to do that, we should calculate the number of characters that we want to reveal:

```
m = lrint((factor2 - factor) * Double(nonSpaces))
```

To pick three indices to reveal randomly, we shuffle `indices` and then replace the `m` first indices :

```
indices.shuffle()
var u = t
for i in 0..<m {
    let index = indices[i]
    u.replaceSubrange(index..<u.index(after: index), with: String(s[index]))
}
indices.removeSubrange(0..<m)

print(u)   //For example: _e__o _l__g_ou_d
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote `StringRevealer` struct, that handle all revealing logic for you:

```swift
/// Hide all unicode letter characters as `_` symbol.
struct StringRevealer {

    /// We need mapping between index of string character and his position in state array.
    /// This struct represent one such record
    private struct Symbol: Hashable {
        let index: String.Index
        let position: Int
    }

    private let originalString: String
    private var currentState: [Character]
    private let charactersCount: Int
    private var revealed: Int
    var revealedPercent: Double {
        return Double(revealed) / Double(charactersCount)
    }
    private var unrevealedSymbols: Set<Symbol>

    init(_ text: String) {
        originalString = text
        var state: [Character] = []
        var symbols: [Symbol] = []
        var count = 0
        var index = originalString.startIndex
        var i = 0
        while index != originalString.endIndex {
            let char = originalString[index]
            if CharacterSet.letters.contains(char.unicodeScalars.first!) {
                state.append("_")
                symbols.append(Symbol(index: index, position: i))
                count += 1
            } else {
                state.append(char)
            }
            index = originalString.index(after: index)
            i += 1
        }
        currentState = state
        charactersCount = count
        revealed = 0
        unrevealedSymbols = Set(symbols)
    }

    /// Current state of text. O(n) conplexity
    func text() -> String {
        return currentState.reduce(into: "") { $0.append($1) }
    }

    /// Reveal one random symbol in string
    mutating func reveal() {
        guard let symbol = unrevealedSymbols.randomElement() else { return }
        unrevealedSymbols.remove(symbol)
        currentState[symbol.position] = originalString[symbol.index]
        revealed += 1
    }

    /// Reveal random symbols on string until `revealedPercent` > `percent`
    mutating func reveal(until percent: Double) {
        guard percent <= 1 else { return }
        while revealedPercent < percent {
            reveal()
        }
    }
}

var revealer = StringRevealer("Hello товарищ! ")
print(revealer.text())
print(revealer.revealedPercent)
for percent in [0.25, 0.45, 0.8] {
    revealer.reveal(until: percent)
    print(revealer.text())
    print(revealer.revealedPercent)
}
```

It use `CharacterSet.letters` inside, so most of languages should be supported, emoji ignored and not-alphabetic characters as well.